# How to redirect in after executes the query php

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $_POST['name'];
$data1 = $_POST['id'];
$c = 0;

foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE ".$table_comp." SET score = " . $data[$c][$value] . " where id = " . $value .";" ;
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $c++;
} 
header('Location: http://www.csscorecard.com/admin/?id=$id');
```

I have problem in my redirect there is an error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/csscorecard/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/ajax/submit.php:3) in /home/csscorecard/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/ajax/submit.php on line 54

Comment: use javascript instead of headers

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and what is being outputted?

Comment: refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @DivyankMunjapara will you give a sample

Comment: @chris85 value of an input type

Comment: Store it in a session variable, redirect, then use (session) variable as needed.

Comment: there should be no HTML or echo present above your header code.

Comment: @LeorahSumarong can you show us full page code?

Comment: Well my comments are going unaddressed, good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Please check your code for any output before using `header('Location:http://www.somewhere.com');`. Even a whitespace can generate this error, so check code for output in `submit.php` line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use javascript instead of headers.

you can use this code to redirect

```
<?php

echo "<script>window.location.href = 'http://www.csscorecard.com/admin/?id=".$id."'</script>";

?>
```

Comment: If we post the form using javascript then only we can use this..writing javascript in PHP script is not a valid way...`header` facilitates to  Send a raw HTTP header

Comment: you are right @Nidhi, but he's seems to sending request through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite complex to give answer in this case without seeing whole file code. In many cases this error shown. but for header location you should put exit:

```
exit(header("Location: http://www.csscorecard.com/admin/?id=$id"));
```

Comment: Exit wont help if `header` is after* output.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  `ob_start();`  top of the file